# jQuery keyup or click not responding right away, why?

Tags: jquery, sum, click, keyup

I have a row of inputs for quantities and I sum the total. I have it working, but there seems to be a lag for when the price total shows up!

The quantity summing works nicely. The price summing seems to happen after clicking, or tabbing, or using the number input select arrows, although not every time! I am using the "keyup" and "click" in the .on function.

Anyway to get this to work the way the quantity summing is working?

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/Bigfootbud1/ht573vps/7/

```
**THIS PRICE SUMMING CODE BELOW DOES NOT RESPOND RIGHT AWAY!**
// ********** LADIES PRICE TOTALS **********
$(document).on('click keyup', '.item1l', function() {
$('.item1l').each(function() {
var qty = parseInt($('.item1ltotal').val(), 10);
var price = parseFloat($('.price').text());
$('#total').text((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
});
});

**THIS CODE BELOW WORKS GREAT FOR SUMMING QUANTITY TOTALS - NICELY 
RESPONSIVE - NO ISSUES WITH IT**
// ********** LADIES QUANTITY TOTALS **********
$(document).on('click keyup', ".item1l", function() {
var sum = 0;
$(".item1l").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
});
$(".item1ltotal").val(sum);    
});
```

Comment: Why do you need two different handlers? The way your code is, the first handler will trigger first, even though it depens on the second one (`.item1ltotal` is updated there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are separating stuff that respond to the same event(s). Put them together

```
    $(document).on('click keyup', '.item1l', function() {
      $('.item1l').each(function() {
        // **THIS PRICE SUMMING CODE BELOW DOES NOT RESPOND RIGHT AWAY!**
        // ********** LADIES PRICE TOTALS **********
        var qty = parseInt($('.item1ltotal').val(), 10);
        var price = parseFloat($('.price').text());
        $('#total').text((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));

        //   SUMMATION OF CATEGORY QTY TOTALS
        // ********** LADIES QUANTITY TOTALS **********
        var sum = 0;
        $(".item1l").each(function() {
          sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $(".item1ltotal").val(sum);
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/luenib/k2nj6d8w/

Comment: THANKS! Seems to work great! BUTT... I forgot to mention that the math seems not to be accurate after adding all 6 input values... Adding 1 item of all inputs gives a total of $67.51 ! It seems to add on an extra penny or two, depending on quantity of items! What's up with that???

Comment: I see. You are multiplying an int and a float. The float, for some reason, is taking the value of 11.2511. You need to change the `var price` line with `var price = parseFloat($('.price').text()).toFixed(2);` See my updated fiddle.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it on my live test page from my godaddy account and it does not sum the price totals at all now... I do have the prices loading by-way of a "config" file, and use an include "xxxxxxxxxxx.php"; file to get the prices to display. Any ideas why the prices are not being totaled at all now? I thought I ran across an article that mentioned that dynamically loading stuff doesn't work in some way.......?.

Comment: Also.... I do have many items. Do I just make copies of this code for each item (just change the item number, etc.) or is there a way to DRY the code? I have 15 ladies items. Am I stuck with having to create 15 blocks of the code, 1 for each item?

Comment: Are you talking about the shopping cart? If so, take a look at the modifications I made to the code here https://jsfiddle.net/luenib/7jykxwvq/ Each table has its own id, which si supposed to be the id of the product being displayed. No need to copy the jQuery code for each product. You'll notice some correction on how to calculate the totals.

Comment: What you are doing with jQuery is correct. `$(document).on('click keyup', '.item1l', function() {}` is how to target your dynamically created elements.

Comment: leunib... I really don't want to reformat all the code.... :( You removed the PHP echo's for the pricing info... Can I use the PHP include with jQuery the way I am trying too??

Comment: The way you pull your data and populate your HTML table is independent of how your jQuery is going to handle that data. I hard coded the prices, but you can use PHP, Python, ASP, a CSV file, or any other tool to extract your data..

Comment: Luenib.....    I understand that. price summation no longer works when I use the php include for the price data. does using a php include interfere with jquery onload?

Comment: PHP and jQuery: Two different things. PHP is going to pull your data from wherever you have it and put it in your HTML; jQuery is going to take the data from your HTML and process it. What I would do to test my code within your PHP code is to replace my hard coded prices with PHP code `<?php echo $price1l_xx ?>` Then I would place my jQuery code at the bottom of everything.

Comment: I FOUND MY ANSWER TO SUBSEQUENT QUESTION - ABSOLUTE BONEHEAD MISTAKE!!! :) Having a "$" sign before the price digits being loaded with the PHP include file was preventing the jQuery from calculating the sum of the prices! I removed the dollar sign and all is well with the world!!! :) Thanks everyone for trying!

Comment: The "$" is supposed to be between a `<br>` and the `<span>` that contains the price, right? `<br> $ <span id='total'>0.00</span>`

Comment: luenib......... Yes. I had to add it to my HTML like you said. I was loading the price from the php include config file as: $sm = '$11.25'; when it should have been: $sm = '11.25'; No dollar sign in the php config file works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179353/discussion-between-bigfootbud-and-luenib).